# ios/objective-c: NSDateFormatter error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

The following code is not converting a string into a date as I would hope.

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
    NSString *starttimestr = feedElement[@"starttime"];
    NSLog(@"starttimestr%@",starttimestr);//this returns 'starttimestr  NSString *  @"2015-10-20 14:30:00"  0x1765ddc0'
    NSDate *starttime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:starttimestr];
    NSLog(@"starttime%@",starttime);//this returns nil
```

Can anyone see what is going wrong?

Comment: Your date string in `starttimestr ` does not match the date format you set in `dateFormatter`, You want something like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. Why would a format string containing `T`, fractional seconds and a timezone work when none of that is in your time string?

Comment: Awesome!.  It is now returning a value.  However there is a 4 hour difference?  starttimestr2015-10-20 14:30:00
starttime2015-10-20 18:30:00 +0000 What might explain that?

Comment: At a guess - this is probably your timezone difference. There are hundreds of questions on SO about dealing with date / times because it is tricky to get it correct. You need to make sure that all times in your app are stored in GMT and then only localised on display. If you have not read the Apple documentation already then you MUST read it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dateFormat` has to match the format of the string for it to work. So you can get rid of the `'T'` and the time zone stuff since none of that is actually in the string.

Comment: You are right that formatting was issue.  Using Robotic Cat's format above, I got it to work